# Android/Kotlin - Select current fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

On my action, I use the `onBackPressed()` method. When I compare the `fragment` that triggered the event, the `id` is never the same and always falls into the else-statement. What's wrong?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val navHost = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val pressed = navHost?.childFragmentManager.fragments?.get(0) as IOnBackPressed
    var currentFragment = navHost?.childFragmentManager.fragments?.get(0)

    pressed?.onBackPressed()?.takeIf { it }?.let {

        when (currentFragment.id) {
            R.id.myfragmet -> {
                // implementation
            }
            else -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know from what `fragment` I returning  when I press the back button, so that I can do the necessary action. Let me simplify the code:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

// get the nav host in the action
val navHost = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

// get the current fragment in the nav host
var currentFragment = navHost?.childFragmentManager.fragments?.get(0)

// Verify the fragment to do a action
when (currentFragment.id) {
        R.id.myfragmet -> {
            // implementation
        }
        else -> {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

}

But the `currentFragment.Id` is never equals `R.id.myfragemnt`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you provide further informations? If you want to have callback when the user navigates back you'd need another approach.

Comment: where do you declared `R.id.myfragmet`?

Comment: @J.Hegg I edited my post for better understanding

Comment: @snachmsm this is a fragment

Comment: but where do you declared this `id` thinking it's for `Fragment`? `Fragment`s doesn't have their `id`s, your `currentFragment.id` is probably containers `id`, which is created under the hood by `navHost` instance

Comment: consider checking `if(currentFragment is YourFragment)` (`is` in Kotlin is an instance check, in Java you can use `instanceof`) instead of comparing `id` (which probably is same containers `id`)